# Return the index of the list with the same element

Tags: python, list, indexing

I want to return the index of the list elements, but for repeated elements, it returns the first inde

```py
X=['m','t','z','m']
For i in x:
   Print(x.index(i))
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
0
```

Expected output:

```
0
1
2
3
```

My problem is on index m
What should I do if it doesn't search the list from the be?

Comment: You need to explain how you are using `index` for someone to give an answer that makes any sense.

Comment: Why would you need to search the list to find the indexes of all elements?  That's just a sequence of consecutive integers - `for i in range(len(x)):` would iterate over them.  If you need both the indexes and values, `for idx, val in enumerate(x):` is the answer.

Comment: Your code is not valid Python.  Keywords should not be capitalized.  Capitalization of variables must be consistent.  Always check your code runs before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can use enumerate and map, but remember that enumerate and map returns an iterable. To view the values you can convert them to list by list() and print them.</s>

```
foo = enumerate(['m','t','z','m'])
print(list(foo)) # [(0, 'm'), (1, 't'), (2, 'z'), (3, 'm')]

# now we have tuples of index and value
# next we use map to just get the index, a.k.a first value
bar = map(lambda x: x[0], foo) 
print(list(bar)) # [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Edit: As @jasonharper said, range() can simply do the job if index is all you want

```
baz = ['m','t','z','m']
foo = range(len(baz)) # 0 1 2 3

# if you only want the index of certain value you can do
bar = filter(lambda x: baz[x] == "m", foo)
print(list(bar)) # [0, 3]
```

but remember that range() and filter() returns an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `enumerate`:

```py
for index, element in enumerate(X):
    print(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, element in enumerate(X):
    print(index)
```